# No routes matches error in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the following error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"settings", :format=>nil}
```

while trying to implement settings/new.

My settings/new.html is as follows:

```
<h1>New setting</h1>

<%= form_for @setting  do |f| %>
  <% if @setting.errors.any? %>  
  <div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2><%= pluralize(@setting.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this setting from being saved:</h2>  
    <ul>  
    <% @setting.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
      <li><%= msg %></li>  
    <% end %>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  
  <% end %> 
</br></br>


Id: <%= f.text_field :id %><br>
Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br>

<%= f.submit "Create" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<% end %>
```

My routes.rb file for settings is:

```
resources :settings do
    member do
     post 'add'
     post 'remove'
     get 'settings/id'
    end

    collection do
     get  'add'
     get  'list' => "settings#index"
     post 'get_settings'
     get  'get_settings'
    end
  end

  resources :settings
```

My settings controllers:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /Settings
  # GET /Settings.json
  def index
    @settings = Setting.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @settings }
    end
  end

  # GET /Settings/1
  # GET /Settings/1.json
  def show
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @setting }
    end
  end

  # GET /Settings/new
  # GET /Settings/new.json
  def new
    @setting = Setting.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @setting }
    end
  end

  # GET /Settings/1/edit
  def edit
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /Settings
  # POST /Settings.json
  def create
    @setting = Setting.new(params[:setting])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @Setting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @setting, notice: 'Lov value was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @setting, status: :created, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /Settings/1
  # PUT /Settings/1.json
  def update
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @Setting.update_attributes(params[:setting])
        format.html { redirect_to @setting, notice: 'Lov value was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /Settings/1
  # DELETE /Settings/1.json
  def delete
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
    @setting.deleted = 1
    @setting.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to settings_url }
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
    end
  end
end
```

My rake routes is as follows:-

```
               add_settings POST   /settings/:id/add(.:format)            settings#add

            remove_settings POST   /settings/:id/remove(.:format)         settings#remove

       settings_id_settings GET    /settings/:id/settings_id(.:format)    settings#settings_id

         add_settings_index GET    /settings/add(.:format)                settings#add

        list_settings_index GET    /settings/list(.:format)               settings#index

get_settings_settings_index POST   /settings/get_settings(.:format)       settings#get_settings

                           GET    /settings/get_settings(.:format)     settings#get_settings

                            GET    /settings(.:format)                    settings#index

                            POST   /settings(.:format)                    settings#create

                            GET    /settings/new(.:format)                settings#new

                            GET    /settings/:id/edit(.:format)           settings#edit

                            GET    /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#show

                            PUT    /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#update

                            DELETE /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#destroy

                            GET    /settings(.:format)                    settings#index

                            POST   /settings(.:format)                    settings#create

                            GET    /settings/new(.:format)                settings#new

                            GET    /settings/:id/edit(.:format)           settings#edit

                            GET    /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#show

                            PUT    /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#update

                            DELETE /settings/:id(.:format)                settings#destroy
```

Please check it and let me know.

Comment: did you use 'rails generate scaffold Settings', command ?http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Comment: @ajt 
Yes I did use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Create` action is redirecting to `Show` after successful save.

However, your `routes.rb` does not have an entry for `Show`, even though your controller has a `Show` method.

Can you try running this command `rake routes`? This will list out all the valid routes of your rails application.

Comment: @ SrikanthVenugopalan I have edited the question can u please check and let me know.

Comment: .please check and let me know

Comment: @PeeVee, I am looking into it, my suspicion is that there is a typo somewhere (probably pluralization), am trying to guess where. Could be easier if I had the code to play with.

Comment: First guess - in your Create, the if block has `@Setting.save` with capital 'S'. Can you try saving the `@setting`?

Comment: at what line # do you have the error ?
I suspect `@Setting` is causing problems for you.
A stack trace might be better.

Comment: @swap.nil how do you implement that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use resources :settings in your routes file and rails RESTFUL routes will take care of everything. You dont need to explicitly state the HTTP verbs for restful routing.
Also in your create and update actions of your controller use @setting instead of @Setting.